# Update database column data via sql query

Tags: sql

I have a requirement where there is a database column that stores DateTime such as 24-01-2015 22:31:49. Now, I can many such rows with different values in the column.

I need a query to update the column's data to 24-01-2015 00:00:00 for each row. (Basically convert datetime to date and save it in the same place).

I have to do it in SQL layer as doing it in my Application level (Java) is not feasible for huge number of records.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution depends on the database.  Here are exampels:

MySQL and DB2:

```
update t
    set col = ate(col;
```

SQL Server 2008+:

```
update t
    set col = cast(col as date);
```

Oracle:

```
update t
    set col = trunc(col);
```

Postgres (and Postgres-derived databases):

```
update t
    set col = date_trunc('day', col);
```

Teradata:

```
update t
    set col = trunc(col, 'd');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET date_time_col = CONCAT(date(date_time_col), ' 00:00:00')
```

Explanation: the **DATE** function will extract the date part of the datetime string. And the CONCAT function will add the 00:00:00 at the end of date.

Answer (score 0):

```
update your_table
set datetimeColumn = date(datetimeColumn)
```